# ALMACENAR DATOS EN UN FICHERO DEPENDIENDO DE LA INICIAL DEL APELLIDO

Tags: java, netbeans-11.2

Pues me gustaría que me ayudaran a encontrar una solución con un problema que tengo.

En la universidad me dejaron realizar un programa, en el cual se tiene que hacer un formulario donde tenga las cajas de texto para ingresar el apellido, nombre y número telefónico de una persona, y luego de ingresar los datos, se deben de guardar en un archivo de texto pero me pidieron que si el apellido ingresado empieza con la letra A, que se guardara en un archivo de texto llamado "A.txt"; si llevara el apellido una L, entonces que se guardara en un archivo de texto llamado "L.txt" y si empezara el apellido con una M, que se guardara en un archivo de texto llamado "M.txt".

Mi problema es que no sé como hacer la condición necesaria para que el programa sepa que, dependiendo de la letra con la que empiece el apellido, los datos se almacenen en un archivo dependiendo de que letra sea.

Adjunto el código que he realizado:

```
    FileWriter fichero1 = null;
    FileWriter fichero2 = null;
    FileWriter fichero3 = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try
    {
        if(txtApellidos.getText().equals("A")){

        fichero1 = new FileWriter("c:/Prueba Programa/A.txt",true);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fichero1);

        pw.println(txtApellidos.getText()+" "+txtNombre.getText()+" "+txtTelefono.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Contacto Agregado Exitosamente");
        txtApellidos.setText(" ");
        txtNombre.setText(" ");
        txtTelefono.setText(" ");

        }
        else if (txtApellidos.getText().equals("L")){


        fichero2 = new FileWriter("c:/Prueba Programa/L.txt",true);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fichero2);

        pw.println(txtApellidos.getText()+" "+txtNombre.getText()+" "+txtTelefono.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Contacto Agregado Exitosamente");
        txtApellidos.setText(" ");
        txtNombre.setText(" ");
        txtTelefono.setText(" ");   

        }
        else if(txtApellidos.getText().equals("M")){

        fichero3 = new FileWriter("c:/Prueba Programa/M.txt",true);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fichero3);

        pw.println(txtApellidos.getText()+" "+txtNombre.getText()+" "+txtTelefono.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Contacto Agregado Exitosamente");
        txtApellidos.setText(" ");
        txtNombre.setText(" ");
        txtTelefono.setText(" ");    

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       try {
       // Nuevamente aprovechamos el finally para 
       // asegurarnos que se cierra el fichero.
       if (null != fichero1)
          fichero1.close();
       else if(null != fichero2)
           fichero2.close();
       else if(null != fichero3)
           fichero3.close();
       } catch (Exception e2) {
          e2.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Ya he corrido el programa y no me da error alguno, y si en las condiciones, en el paréntesis del equals por ejemplo coloco: equals("Aguilar"), equals("Lopez") y equals("Martinez), si corro el programa e ingreso alguno de estos apellidos en las cajas de texto y pulso el botón de guardado, sí respeta la condición y dependiendo de que letra tenga al inicio, crea el archivo de texto correspondiente.

Entonces la pregunta que saldría de todo esto sería:

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a saber que es lo que tengo que colocar para que cualquier apellido que inicie con ya sea, A,L o M pueda ser guardado en el archivo de texto que le corresponda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

existe un metodo que puede extraer partes de un String, a continuacion te indico como hacerlo, ya solo debes poner esa letra en las comparaciones del equals de tu codigo

```
  String primeraLetra="";
        String palabra = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingresa una palabra");
        //el metodo substring sustrae letras o conjunto de letras
        //el primer parametro es la posicion de la letra a extraer
        //el segundo parametro es la letra siguiente, se indica como final
        primeraLetra=palabra.substring(0,1);
        System.out.println(primeraLetra);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.
Acabo de implementar el método que me acabas de compartir y con eso ya pude conseguir lo quería.